# Fourier transform of $\cos w_0t$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I know final result of Fourier transform of $\cos w_0t$ (from table), but how it is calculated, step by step? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It is here mandatory to show some effort, to get better help. What are your own thoughts?

Comment: Fourier transform in $L^2\left(-\frac{\pi}{w_0},\frac{\pi}{w_0}\right)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

My deinition of Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}[f](x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) e^{-itx} dt
\end{equation*}
Now just simply compute the integral, and use that the Dirac delta function is also given by
\begin{equation*}
\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} dt
\end{equation*}